# How to edit tables in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a code in python 3.x which uses matplotlib.

```
colLabels = ["Name", "Number"]
data = [["Peter", 17], ["Sara", 21], ["John", 33]]
the_table = ax.table(cellText=data,
                     colLabels=colLabels,
                     loc='center')
plt.pause(0.1)
```

The above code is in a loop, now I want to search for the row with "Peter" in first column (it's unique) and edit it so that in every iteration the entry in second column changes. I could clear whole `ax` and add new table but it's inefficient (I would be redrawing table with multiple rows every 0.1s)

Is there a way to edit this in matplotlib (and how) or should I use some other library (which)?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at Pandas, which comes with the Dataframe type for tables. It has rich editing capabilities (also vectorized) and also interfaces well with matplotlib. However, I don't know if I really got your question. Are you trying to partially update a plot on display?

Comment: Have you considered using [Matplotlib Animation API](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) instead?

Comment: @ypnos I want to edit whats inside `data` and see the change on `the_table` (which is being displayed)
**edit**: also do it efficiently, because what I am doing now is deleting `the_table` and creating new one with updated `data`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text in a matplotlib table can be updated by chosing the cell and set the text of the cell's `_text` attribute. E.g.

```
the_table.get_celld()[(2, 1)].get_text().set_text("new text")
```

will update the cell in the third row and second column.

An animated example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,2))
colLabels = ["Name", "Number"]
data = [["Peter", 1], ["Sara", 1], ["John", 1]]
the_table = ax.table(cellText=data,
                     colLabels=colLabels,
                     loc='center')

def update(i):
    the_table.get_celld()[(1, 1)].get_text().set_text(str(i))
    the_table.get_celld()[(2, 1)].get_text().set_text(str(i*2))
    the_table.get_celld()[(3, 1)].get_text().set_text(str(i*3))

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=20, interval=400)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Finding out which cell needs to be updated, would probably best be done using the data instead of reading it from the table.

```
inx = list(zip(*data))[0].index("Peter")
```

gives you the index 0, such that the cell can be accessed via
`the_table.get_celld()[(inx+1, 1)]` (note the `+1`, which is there because of the table headline).

Comment: Do you know how to add a row to this table?

Comment: You can use `the_table.add_cell()` but it might be a little bit or work to get it display nicely.